# App Engine: Can't get any Tutorial working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I try to develop an App Engine project for Android, but I have bugs again and again. I tried to do 3 tutorials in the last days, but got none of them working...

[Tutorial 1: Create App Engine Connected Android Project](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae)
When creating an App Engine Connected Android Project, I get the following error in the MainActivity: RegisterActivity cannot be resolved to a type.
When i googled this error, I saw that many people had the same error 1 year ago, but nobody could give a good solution yet. Has google been able to solve this bug yet?..

Tutorial 2:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/create_project

This Tutorial uses Maven. I tried to generate the project with following command, because I am not able to do that with the interactive mode:
"mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.google.appengine.samples.helloendpoints -DartifactId=helloendpoints -DarchetypeArtifactId=appengine-skeleton-archetype -DinteractiveMode=false". 
It fails and tells me that the archetype doesn't exist.. (appengine-skeleton-archetype)
Well, I don't know what to do here...

Tutorial 3: 
https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial

At "Modify the Client Application", when I replace the Code from MainActivity01, I get errors like "CloudEndpointUtils cannot be resolved", because in the MobileAssistant src folder the class CloudEndpointUtils was not created!

Conclusion: Seems like most of the documentation is not up-to-date and the google plugins are pretty bugged... Maybe somebody knows how to solve those errors?

Is there any Tutorial, which is up-to-date and, which shows how to build an easy application for android with appengine and which WORKS? I would like to complete just ANY tutorial and have a stable basic project...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation does work, so the problems may lie in the configuration of your tools.  You show considerable persistence, so consider switching to a new installation of tools (Eclipse or whatever).  Also prove your tools by building *and deploying* simpler AppEngine-only projects first before aiming higher for Android-to-AppEngine projects.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I had reinstalled eclipse several times because of those and other bugs.. But I think I had installed it correctly with the latest plugins...
Now, to be sure that I install it definitely correctly, I have completely formatted my computer (reinstall windows 8.1)

So, in order to be sure that I do everything absolute correctly, which of the following possible ways to install the whole eclipse setup is better?

1. Install eclipse kepler WITHOUT ADT. Then install all the ADT-plugins and google-plugins, and then install everything necessary from android SDK manager.
2. Install ADT Bundle (comes with eclipse juno atm and is version 22.3). Then install google-plugins and update ADT-plugins from 22.3 to 22.6.1. Then install everything necessary from android SDK manager.

I know this shouldn't make a real difference, but I have done that often enough and I still had errors. This time I want to be sure to do it completely right!